# In Python, how do I access an objects property if I know its identifier?

Tags: python

Here is a simple class:

```
class Daz:
    def __init__ (self, vName, vValue):
        self.Name = vName
        self.Value = vValue
```

And I can create an instance of the class, added to a dictionary thus:

```
dictOfDaz = []
dictOfDaz.append(Daz('Obj1',25))
dictOfDaz.append(Daz('Obj2',35))
```

So, I now want to access the vValue property of one of the instances where I know the Name.

In pseudo-code:

```
Get vValue from instance of Daz where Daz.Name == 'Obj1'
```

I don't want to loop through the dictionary because I know the specific object names I need to reference and having to do

```
for d in dictOfDaz:
  if d.Name == 'Obj1' or d.Name == 'Obj2':
    do_this
```

seems inefficient to me.

**Update:**
Having got confused between a list and a dict, the solution (as pointed pointed out by Tom and others) is as follows:

```
class Daz:
    def __init__ (self, vName, vValue):
        self.Name = vName
        self.Value = vValue

dictOfDaz = {}

dictOfDaz['Obj1'] = Daz('Obj1',25)
dictOfDaz['Obj2'] = Daz('Obj2',35)
dictOfDaz['Obj3'] = Daz('Obj3',45)
dictOfDaz['Obj4'] = Daz('Obj4',55)
```

This then allows me to access the values of the instances by:

```
print getattr(dictOfDaz['Obj1'], 'Value')
```

Which solves my problem, perfectly!

Comment: You're referring to a list as a dictionary, which is something quite different.  In your example, what you really have is listOfDaz, not dictOfDaz.

Comment: It would be more efficient if you had a dictionary `{name: Daz(name, value), ...}`, but with a list you're stuck with the `O(n)` iteration you currently have.

Comment: What you have is a list of key/value pairs. A list of key/value pairs does not allow you to efficiently look up values for keys. That's why we have `dict` instead.

Comment: use a `dict` to store objects. e.g. `dictOfDaz['obj1'] = Daz('obj1',25)`, and access the object by key `dictOfDaz['obj1']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are using a list, not a dict.  If you use a genuine dict, indexed by Name, then you can look up your objects by name:

```
dictOfDaz = {}

daz = Daz('Obj1',25)
dictOfDaz[daz.Name] = daz

daz = Daz('Obj2',35)
dictOfDaz[daz.Name] = daz
```

Now you can refer to `dictOfDaz['Obj1']` and `dictOfDaz['Obj2']`.

Comment: Thank you all!! I am new to Python and obviously got confused between list and dictionary! I couldn't figure out why I couldn't solve my problem - makes perfect sense now! I will edit / update the question to show the fix...